# how to display innerhtml of text area content in popup

Tags: angular, typescript

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) {
      data = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML + document.getElementById('new')+ '<br>';

    }

    fun(){
      document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=this.data.name;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body (load)="fun()">
<h1 mat-dialog-title> {{data.name}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two way binding from text area to get the text from there.

```
<textarea [(ngModel)] = 'text'></textarea>
```

in typescript declare variable *text*

You should use angular innerHTML property binding to display 'text'

```
<div [innerHTML]='text'></div>
```